# Makefile execute for one option or loop over all of them

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a set of plants (let's call them `plant_1`, `plant_2` etc.) and several steps to process their data. I want to create a makefile that can process data for one plant or for all at once.

It's the same set of Python commands for every plant: E.g. `python join_data plant_1`, `python clean_data plant_1`, `python process_data plant_1` etc.
I want to avoid repeating myself by writing down

```
join_data_plant_1:
   python join_data plant_1
```

etc.
I know I can simply write `python join_data $@`, but then the target would have to be `plant_1` and I couldn't write down the rules for the other steps in the same way. Also I could set `PLANT = plant_1` as a variable and just write

```
join_$PLANT:
   python join_data $PLANT
```

but then I do not know how to write a rule to generate all plants at once.

What's an elegant an non-redundant way to write this makefile?

I hope it's not a duplicate; I'm new to `make`, so it's hard for me to search for the right terms.

### EDIT

To answer the comments: No, I do not just modify one file in place. The whole recipe looks approximately like this for `plant_1`:

```
joined_data_plant_1.pckl: data/plant_1/raw_data.xlsx join_data
   python join_data plant_1

cleaned_data_plant_1.pckl: joined_data_plant_1.pckl clean_data
   python clean_data plant_1

processed_data_plant_1.pckl: cleaned_data_plant_1.pckl process_data
   python process_data plant_1
```

Comment: You can access the file system with `$(wildcard plant_*)` to determine the plants you have as a list of strings. You can further use this list as targets by adding a suffix `$(addsuffix ..)` to shape the appropriate target file names.

Comment: What input files do you start with, and what output files do you wind up with? Is it just several stages of modifying `plant_1` in place?

Comment: It's very simple to do, but since you've only shown us one "step" and not defined others or how they fit together (do they create output files?  Do they have to run in a certain order, where the output of one step is used as the input to another?  Etc.), we can't really give you an answer.

Comment: @MadScientist I changed my question to make it more precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
ALL_PLANTS = plant_1 plant_2 plant_3

all: $(ALL_PLANTS)

$(ALL_PLANTS): % : processed_data_%.pckl

.PHONY: all $(ALL_PLANTS)

joined_data_%.pckl: data/%/raw_data.xlsx join_data
        python join_data $*

cleaned_data_%.pckl: joined_data_%.pckl clean_data
        python clean_data $*

processed_data_%.pckl: cleaned_data_%.pckl process_data
        python process_data $*
```

Now if you run `make` or `make all` it will build all of them.  If you run `make plant_1` or `make plant_1 plant_3` will build just those.

Comment: This works like a charm and it exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much! :) (Just one additional question, out of curiosity: Why was make programmed so that the `%` sign cannot be used as the target pattern in the recipe, but so that you have to use `$*` instead? I find this very counter-intuitive...)

Comment: A recipe is a shell script.  Make doesn't try to actually parse the recipe or run commands in it, it simply sends the entire thing (one line at a time) to a shell to run.  Make treats the recipe as simply a block of text.  The only thing it does with that text is replace variable/function invocations, which all start with `$`.  This means any `$` that needs to be passed through to the shell must be escaped as `$$`... this is already difficult for people to remember.  If it also replaced `%` then there would be _two_ characters that had to be escaped.

Comment: Also, every recipe supports a full list of automatic variables (see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html ) and only one of those refers to `$*` so it would be weird to have all of them be `$<x>`, except one which is just `%`.  And, `$*` can even be set in explicit rules, where `%` doesn't appear at all in the target or prerequisites.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you!